# ¿Cómo puedo implementar un input filter (mediante el evento onkeyup) en un .twig? (symfony)

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Soy nuevo utilizando Symfony y he desarrollado una aplicación CRUD básica. Me gustaría implementar un filtro (mediante el evento onkeyup a poder ser) para buscar X usuario (por su email por ejemplo) dentro del listado del global de usuarios.

He estado probando mediante js pero sin éxito. Obtenía el valor del input pero no conseguía equiparar su valor con el campo en cuestión a la hora de aplicar el filtro (por ejemplo: introduzco pepe dentro del input y el listado de usuarios en cuanto dejara de escribir me debería devolver todos los usuarios que cuentan o empiecen con la palabra pepe en su email).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido solucionar mi problema mediante jquery. Os adjunto el código que he utilizado para su correcto funcionamiento. Donde *#myInput* es el id de mi **input** y *#myTable tr* es el id del body de mi **tabla**. Lo he implementado a mi aplicación y consigue filtrar los usuarios correctamente (gracias al método onkeyup por cada letra que voy escribiendo se van acotando los resultados de dicho filtro). Espero que le sirva a alguien de ayuda en un futuro.

**plantilla base.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        
         ...

         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

         ...

    </head>
<body>
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

**cualquier plantilla .twig**

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

...

{% block body %}

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
                var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                $("#myTable tr").filter(function() {
                    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                });
            });
        });
</script>

<input type="text" id="myInput" class="form-control" placeholder="..." aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">

...

<tbody id="myTable">

...

{% endblock %}
```